# Htaccess URL masking to specific folder

Tags: .htaccess, url, mask

I have the following problem.
I need when people access to www.mydomain.com they really access to www.mydomain.com/folder, and they keep seeing www.mydomain.com in the URL.

How can this be done with de .htaccess of my server?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a .htaccess file in the root of the site with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com/$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^../folder

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9/-_.\s]+)?$ ../folder/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?([a-zA-Z0-9/-_.\s]+)$ ../folder/$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

that's all you need.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1 [L]
```

and try to search before you ask something! there are lots of examples like that.

Comment: I search a lot, thank for your answer, but like all the others examples thay I found it gives me error 500

Comment: @user2418362 You should explain what you've done and what error messages you have been getting so we can better help you. Re the 500 error - although highly unlikely, your host may have +FollowSymLinks enabled at the root level and disallowed in its .htaccess; in which case, if you are using +FollowSymLinks it will break your setup (with probably a 500 error)